# Submitting a form with payload in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to automate a form submit for a clinic. The form takes the following parameters (The filled in data is the minimal required data to submit the form)

```
    {'PatientID':'', 
    'ClientId': '<my-computer-id>',
    'ParhId':'', 
    'Phone':'', 
    'Address':'', 
    'IsNewCase': 'True',
    'PatientAdmissionTypeID':'', 
    'ProcedureDuration':'', 
    'ScheduledAnesthesiaType':'', 
    'IsPatientExistenceDialogShow': 'False',
    'PatientMRN': 'test123',
    'PatientFirstName': 'test123',
    'PatientLastName': 'test123',
    'DOB.DatePicker': '2022-06-26',
    'DOB': '06/26/2022',
    'Gender': 'M',
    'Height.InchesIntegral': '',
    'Weight.Value': '',
    'Weight.Units': 'Lbs'
    'SurgicalProcedureCPT':'', 
    'MedicalProcedureID': '',
    'SurgicalLocationID': '80922ba1-269d-eb11-811a-000d3a609173',
    'ProcedureDate.DatePicker': '2022-07-20',
    'ProcedureDate': '7/20/2022 12:00:00 AM',
    'ProcedureTime':''}
```

In order to submit the form, I have to login in to the system. Right now I'm just doing that with a simple button click after providing the login information. Once the program makes it to the add new patient page, I've been inputting the required information into the form through the UI, but that takes longer than I want, and is prone to breaking and bugs. Because this script has to run every day, I need it to be as robust as possible. They've asked me to go through the front end of their website to input the information.

I've tried using the requests module, but when I log in using requests the page doesn't get the necessary javascript and other necessary resources to allow me to send the form. Instead it returns the main page in static html form with dead links. It will allow me to login by sending the correct payload in the login page, but I can't get to the add new patient page after that.

I've also tried using scrapy and scrapy-playwright, haven't been able to figure it out yet, but if that's the route I need to take I can figure it out.

Finally I tried converting the curl request (with the necessary headers and cookies included) into  python code, and that allowed me to login as before, but I still am unable to access the add patients page.

Here's the URL I'm using: 'https://m.epreop.com/Clients/GANS/PatientEncounter/CaseDetail'. This is the URL where the patient data post request is sent.

This url is supposed to redirect the user to the add new patient page. But when I login using requests it just takes me to the broken static page. Maybe there's some firewall I'm not noticing when I login with requests.

My current idea is to login through the UI with selenium to validate my credentials then somehow submit the form to the server once I've logged in that way, but i'm not sure its possible.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from config import username, password
from pprint import pprint
import requests

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=chrome_options)

def main():
    with requests.session() as session:

        driver.get(URL)
        search = driver.find_element(By.ID,"UserName")
        search.send_keys(username)
        search2 = driver.find_element(By.ID,"UserPassword")
        search2.send_keys(password)
        search3 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btnlogin')
        search3.click()
        
        #navigate to add patient page...

        patient_payload = { "patient_payload" }

        session.get(URL)
        response = session.post(URL,data=_patientpayload)

        pprint(response.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Currently 'pprint' returns <Response [200]> but doesn't actually post the data.

Comment: This doesn't work because requests and selenium do not share the session (cookies / auth header)

Comment: Right that's what I thought. Is there any way to do this with another library? Selenium has a selenium.requests module, do you think that would work? It has a post function but I haven't found a good way to use it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the curl, try copying the fetch and put it in like:

````
driver.execute_script(```
  fetch(...)
```)
````

Comment: Do I find the fetch information in the post request form info? Or what do you mean by copy the fetch

Comment: In chrome network panel you can right click a request and copy as curl or copy as fetch